# Is it possible to create an Ubuntu swapfile on an exfat partition?

Tags: swap

I know there are better options out there like a swap partition. But I am just curious if this would be a possible option at all. Does swapfile have to be on a Linux file system?

Comment: Theoretically no. On Linux, it's just another file. However, if `swapon` is giving you trouble, then make the permissions more restrictive in your mount options.

Comment: I've used both *swapfile* and *swap partition* (*swap partition used by default; swapfile added when extra space is required for specific & only occasionally used tasks*). What is available though can vary on product & release details, and you've provided no specifics.

Comment: It's a Very Bad Idea! An exFAT filesystem implies access by a Windows system. Windows, wirh the default "Fast Boot" option can render the partition confusing (therefore mounted read-only) to Linux.Trying to boot or run with a Read-Only swap will lead quickly to disaster. The quote that springs to mind "blowed up real good!".  See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: @waltinator Did you mean NTFS? NTFS is usually used with Windows, while exFAT is usually used with SD cards. I don't think "Fast Boot" will make the exFAT read only, because a reasonable user might remove the SD card and insert it into another computer